# Javascrit ao mover o mouse sobre uma celular, mudar o texto da celula

Tags: javascript, css-hover

Sou novato, estou aprendendo muito no site.

Gostaria que quando toca-se no item 2, muda-se a palavra item 2 para Erva-mate e continua-se acendendo o item 4.

```js
$('.row-1 .column-2').hover(function () {
    $('.row-2 .column-2').toggleClass('active');
});

/*
$('.row-1 .column-2').hover(function(){
    alert("hovered");
    $('.row-2 .column-2').toggleClass('active');
    $('this').toggleClass('active');
});


/*
$('.row-1 .column-2').mouseenter(function(){
  $('.row-1 .column-2').addClass('active');
  $('.row-2 .column-2').addClass('active');
});

$('.row-1 .column-2').mouseleave(function() {
  $('.row-1 .column-2').removeClass('active');
  $('.row-2 .column-2').removeClass('active');
});
*/


/*
$('.row-2 .column-2').hover(function(){
    $('.row-1 .column-2').toggleClass('active');
    $('.row-2 .column-1').toggleClass('active');
});

/*
*/
```

```css
.table-style {
    margin-bottom:15px;
}
.table-style td {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0px;
}
.table-style td span {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #454545;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.table-style td span a {
    color: #8d8d8d;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.active {
    background: red;
}
.active span a {
    color: #000;
}
.table-style td p a:hover {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tablepress-71" class="table-style" width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr class="row-1">
        <td class="column-1"><span><a href="#">Item 1</a></span>
        </td>
        <td class="column-2"><span><a href="#">Item 2</a></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row-2">
        <td class="column-1"><span><a href="#">Item 3</a></span>
        </td>
        <td class="column-2"><span><a href="#">Item 4</a></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Não precisa de JS pra isso. Usa só CSS

Comment: Mas como amigo?

Comment: Um exemplo que eu uso...
a{text-decoration:none}
a:hover{text-decoration:underline}

Comment: Pode comentar no CSS para eu ver, procurei no fórum e no google como fazer e não achei.

Comment: Classe "active"         .active:hover{font-color:#0f0;}

Comment: Consegui, valeu

Comment: vou postar a resposta.. marca como resolvido. vlw

Answer (score 0):

Não precisa usar JS pra isso. Dá pra fazer só com CSS:

```css
.item:hover {
  color: #0f0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="item">Texto 1</td>
    <td class="item">Texto 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```